# How to identify the country & change the URL accordingly

Tags: html, http, .htaccess, http-headers

we have three domains one for US, one for UK, and one for Canada. i want that my users should be automatically redirected to country specific URL no matter what domain they open.e.g. if the user is from US and he is opening example.co.uk then he/she should be redirected to example.com.

Comment: Just a word of warning here: as a user, I find this behaviour incredibly annoying and downright rude: I want to be in charge of my computer, and while I appreciate assistance from software, not retaining control makes me feel lost. Consider whether your users might feel the same.

Comment: Do a search for "ip to country" and you'll find various technologies on offer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to identify the country by IP. For example see http://www.ip2location.com/
This will not cover everybody, but should be ok for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:
1) Configure your web server with the `MultiViews` option to look for browser settings and show appropriate page.
2) Use `mod_rewrite / .htaccess` and redirect the user based on `Accept-Language` HTTP header.

For complete details, please see the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/131871/how-to-redirect-to-a-given-page-depending-on-the-user-locale). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was look for a similar solution for one of my clients. Fortunately we were using Wordpress and were able to use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ip2country/ to make country specific content conditions and templates. This plugin leverages Geolite found here http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad's comment cannot be high-lighted enough. Instead of just redirecting could you offer the user to be redirected - or if you just redirect send a banner telling they were redirected and asking whether they wanted not be redirected? If they chose, they wanted not to be redirected, you redirect them back and ensure via extra clause in the URL or by cookie that they would not be redirected forward again.

Just one story to illustrate the annoyance: My new hob is broken. I can't access electrolux.com. I am redirected to electrolux.ch. There seems to be a troubleshooter but the link is broken. The .ch site is for sure not their primary development side and German not their primary site language. The link may work under .com in English, but Electrolux does not allow me test that.

Or, if I am in a country and don't speak the country's language and therefore would want to stay at the original URL and use that language?

Or, think my cousin in another country is sending me a .com link and I can't open it?

There are many annoyance scenarios.

Comment: This is more like discussion / commentary than an answer, afaict. If you're supporting another answer, I'd recommend adding a comment under it.